# How to find out a specific string on https://translations.launchpad.net?

Tags: launchpad, translation

Sometimes I like to offer translation suggestions for strings in my native language on https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu.

Normally, to find out a specific string in launchpad translations, first I try to find out the package of the program which produces/uses that string, then I go on launchpad translations at that package page and I use the search field from the page for that string. Most of the times this method works, but there are cases when it is not working. Let me give you an example from terminal:

```
$ rm blabla
```

The output in English in this case (my case) is:

```
rm: cannot remove blabla: No such file or directory
```

So, first I found out that `rm` is in `coreutils` package, then on launchpad translations at `coreutils` package page, I searched for `cannot remove` and I found it:

- https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/coreutils/+pots/coreutils/fr/+translate?batch=10&show=all&search=cannot+remove

But when I searched for `No such file or directory` nothing has been found:

- https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/coreutils/+pots/coreutils/fr/+translate?batch=10&show=all&search=No+such+file+or+directory

Any idea where can I find in this case the `No such file or directory` string on https://translations.launchpad.net to offer translation suggestions for it? Any help will be appreciated.